# Giving ma'aser to a kohen

Tags: maaser-tithes, halacha, kohen-priest, agriculture

When one separates the "[first tithe](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/961523/jewish/Positive-Commandment-127.htm)", which needs to be given to a *ben Levi*, may he give it to a *kohen* instead on the grounds that he is of *Levi* lineage?

Would this at least work *b'di'avad* to relieve the rest of his crop of *[tevel](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/961797/jewish/Negative-Commandment-153.htm)* status (assuming *t'ruma* had been separated as well) since the *kohen* could use some part of what he received for *ma'aser* as *t'rumas ma'aser* himself (citation needed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the subject of a dispute between R' Akiva and R' Elazar ben Azaryah in Yevamos 86a-b: R' Akiva says that it must be given to a Levi, R' Elazar says it can be given to a Kohen as well. (The Levi'im failed to come with Ezra to Eretz Yisrael, as described in Ezra 8:15, and the Gemara says that he penalized them for this; the underlying argument is exactly what form this penalty took.)

The Mechaber (Yoreh De'ah 331:19) follows R' Akiva and says that it should be given to a Levi, but Rema there cites Tur that it may be given to a kohen instead (in accordance with R' Elazar ben Azaryah's view).