Why doesn't the percentage of terumas maaser mimic terumah gedolah's?
The Torah (Bamidbar 18) says that maaser rishon is meant to compensate the leviyim for their work and is treated precisely as their portion in the land and therefore is obligated in terumah and is completely chulin afterwards.
Terumah has no required amount min hatorah whereas terumas maaser which is the leviyim's terumah is fixed at ten percent.
Why the disparity?

related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/141706/759
